# Sql multiple values in where clause from subquery

Tags: sql, where-clause

Basically, what I am trying to do is: I want a sql query that return all rows from a table where the id is (Some subquery which gives back 20 ids).

Like that:

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE People.ID = (SELECT CreatedBy.PeopleID FROM CreatedBy)
```

Comment: Use `IN` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE People.ID in (SELECT CreatedBy.PeopleID FROM CreatedBy)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was searching for!

Comment: @RogerSchneiter If your question is answered, please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

use `'IN'` rather than `'='`

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE People.ID IN (SELECT CreatedBy.PeopleID FROM CreatedBy)
```

Answer (score 0):

use in instead of =

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE People.ID in (SELECT CreatedBy.PeopleID FROM CreatedBy)
```